# manifest.json display property has invalid option of browser

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, progressive-web-apps, manifest.json

The [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display#Values) seems to state that there are four options for the "display" property within a manifest.json: fullscreen, standalone, minimal-ui and browser

I decided upon 'browser' for one of my apps, but the message from Chrome (Version 76) says "**Manifest 'display' property must be one of 'standalone', 'fullscreen' or 'minimal-ui'**".  The message also appears if I leave 'display' undefined.

Is 'browser' an obsolete option or has it just not made it into the latest Chrome version yet?

(I probably should mention that the message appears in Chrome DevTools>application>manifest).

Comment: As I had no further comment, I have concluded that it is just a bug in Chrome DevTools and have reported it as an issue.  I don't expect any quick fixes though.

Comment: Could you please share the URL of the bug report? I had a quick search around but couldn't find it. I'm guessing anyone who comes across this question might be interested in following it.

Comment: I reported it via the "Report an issue..." option within Chrome. I am not aware of any other places to report Chrome bugs that can be followed.

Comment: Ahh right. They have this bug tracker: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got around to reporting it as a bug.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1330323

The immediate response was...

> The behaviour is seen from M-85.This is  is a non regression issue
> hence marking it as untriaged and requesting some one from dev team to
> look into the issue.

Comment: No further updates as of today.

Answer (score 1):

Valid options for display are `fullscreen`, `standalone`, `minimal-ui` and `browser` according to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display.

In order to show the **Add to Home Screen Prompt**, display must be set to must be one of: `fullscreen`, `standalone`, or `minimal-ui`, see https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

`browser` display option is like leaving the field empty.

When you use `standalone` it looks like native app. When you use `fullscreen` there is no status bar etc. Probably you want to use `standalone`, because `fullscreen` has very specific use-case (e.g. gaming).

Comment: Thanks for answering. Unfortunately you missed the point of my question - Chrome is saying that "browser" is not a valid option.

Comment: Yes, that's still the case. Chrome (devs) seem(s) to only interpret those as valid that make it addable to the home screen.